# Android is screen on or off deprecated isScreenOn()

Tags: android, deprecated

I need to know if user is interacting with device, that's why I used this following code.
I dont know if its ok to use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` this way, so that will work on all versions.?

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        if (pm.isInteractive()) {
            System.out.println("alarm screen ON");
        }
    }
    else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH){
        if(pm.isScreenOn()){
            System.out.println("alarm screen ON");
        }
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("alarm screen OFF");
    }
```

the depracated method is: `isScreenOn()`

Comment: did it work ? please let us know

Comment: yes, this works. And is correct solution.

Comment: It can be correct solution, but definitely not correct code as else with OFF is not reachable, also gives a warning on API level lower than Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH