# Check if user is actively present

Tags: android, user-presence

Is there a way to determine if a user is actively present on phone (not just screen on).

I cannot depend on catching events.  These only fire off at points in time within a BroadcastReceiver:

```
intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)
intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
```

I need a simple way to perform an active check in that moment.  A service is firing off, and I do not want it to fire off while the phone is active (screen on).

Comment: Please provide a precise technical description of "actively present on phone".

Comment: Equivalent of Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT. But want to check it at will. No wait for a Broadcast to tell me.

Answer (score 4):

You can check it through PowerManager class of android SDK.

```
   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
   boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
```

Updated answer:
isScreenOn() method is deprecated, Replace it with isInteractive()

```
   boolean isScreenOn = pm.isInteractive();
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks- looks like this will do the trick. I'll report back if it does not.

Comment: isScreenOn() is deprecated in favor of isInteractive() [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718783/andorid-is-screen-on-or-off-deprecated-isscreenon).